# (MySQL) trigger on column to set all values to zero before update on that column?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Basically I have a column called "ispushed".  Whenever a button on the webpage is pushed all values in that column should be reset to zero except for the row I'm updating, that one should be set to 1.

Something like this

```
CREATE TRIGGER `TR_ispushed` BEFORE UPDATE on `questions`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE  questions set questions.`ispushed` = 0
        WHERE id <> **Current id**
END$$
```

Comment: If you're changing the entire table for a single user action, then effectively designing a single user app.  True?

Comment: True only 1 user can make use of the app at a time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trigger is not what you need to use for implementing such logic. Simple update statement will do it : `UPDATE questions SET is_pushed = CASE WHEN id =[your_id] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`;